# Is it possible to customize the User menu in the upper right corner in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am testing Laravel Nova, and I couldn't find any ressource about adding elements to the upper right menu. I would love to let the user change his details from here.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the file:

/resources/views/vendor/nova/partials/user.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

In Nova 4, you can add menu items in the `boot` method of `App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
    {
        Nova::userMenu(function (Request $request, Menu $menu) {
            if ($request->user()->subscribed()) {
                $menu->append(
                    MenuItem::make('Subscriber Dashboard')
                        ->path('/subscribers/dashboard')
                );
            }

            $menu->prepend(
                MenuItem::make(
                    'My Profile',
                    "/resources/users/{$request->user()->getKey()}"
                )
            );

            return $menu;
        });
    }
```

Resource: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/menus.html#customizing-the-user-menu